# WPF C# how to create THIS binding in code?

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, dependencies

I wonder, how to create this binding, since Line.X2 IS NOT dependency property! :(

```
<Line Y1="0" X1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="0 -2 0 -2" X2="{Binding Path=RenderSize.Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}"/>
```

Comment: Try maybe setting it in the C# code-behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Line.X2 *is* a dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line.x2.aspx) so you can do this in the normal way:

```
myLine.SetBinding(Line.X2Property,
  new Binding("RenderSize.Width")
  {
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(StackPanel), 1)
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add Property yo X2! My fault!