# How to implement WPF Binding Validation in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to generalize the sample provided by Microsoft illustrating how to implement a Binding Validation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation#see-also] by reformulating it all in C#.

(1) I am trying to convert the following XAML binding to C#:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

(2) and the following XAML which creates a red exclamation mark to notify the user of a validation error to C#:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
      <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
      </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

(3) also the XAML which creates a ToolTip to C# that shows the error message is created:

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My goal is to make it reusable in many places by defining a class which can construct/define both the text field and the binding in my program to connect text fields to integer or double type properties. Although similar question was asked before [[WPF C# how to create THIS binding in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444478/wpf-c-sharp-how-to-create-this-binding-in-code]) in this case XAML code for defining the binding and the helper utilities/methods are fairly complex.

Any comment, suggestion, or help would be appreciated.

i.konuk

Comment: UserControl is way to go.

Comment: You are already on the right track by using a `ValidationRule` - don't try and convert this all to C# because you don't need to. Define a global style that you can apply to the TextBox and stick to the bound validation rule. Check [this blog post](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2011/07/taking-data-binding-validation-and-mvvm.html) by me to see if it helps.

Comment: slugster, thank you indeed very much for the suggestion and encouragement. I should have thought of style! I will try and post update if I make progress.